# How do I insert today's date after a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

We have this checkbox on gridview:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkb" runat="server" onclick = "Check_this(this)" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Our users can click to check one box or they can click to check many boxes.

We would like to add another column:

```
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "curDate" SortExpression="curDate" HeaderText = "Date Accepted" />
```

This way, anytime a user checks one or more checkboxes, the date the box was checked is automatically recorded and displayed.

Can you please suggest how I can go about handling this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to postback to the server to do this, or do you want to handle it on the client side? If the former, associate an event handler with the checkbox's click event; if the latter, you'll need to use jQuery.

Comment: date will be displayed in Bound Field ?

Comment: Do you also want to record accepted date in database?

Comment: Do you want to do that on clientside, so is this a javascript or asp.net question?

Comment: @SuperNES you can do it only with javascript, JQuery is not required, it's very sample if it's on client side

Comment: i'll response when the OP specify the side.

Comment: Thanks @Leandro. I am the OP and clientside would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: ok, one little question that changes everything: are you using masterpage?

Comment: Where did my response go?

Sorry @Leandro. I responded that we are not using masterpage.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not versed in asp, so I can't give you the exact code to solve your problem. I can, however, explain how to do it with JavaScript.

In your `Check_this()` function add a line that sets wherever you want to output the date to, to the current date. I'm not sure how you fetch locations in asp, but with plain HTML and JS it'd be `document.getElementById("curDate").innerHTML = new Date()`